# Mvc Deserialize Json to list in foreach

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

First of all, i have been searching overall, and could not find the answer. 
I am getting data from online Rest Api which is in Json format. 
I am trying to make a search app, but cannot search in List.

How can i search in List?

My POCO class:

```
public class rootObject
{
    public List<Product> products { get; set; }
}
    public class Product
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string alias { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
}
```

API Classes:

```
    public static string makeApiCall(string requestUrl)
    {
        var syncClient = new WebClient();
        var content = syncClient.DownloadString(requestUrl);
        Trace.WriteLine(content.ToString());
        return content;
    }

    public static Product GetByISBN(string isbn)
    {
            string requestUrl = string.Format(baseUrl + isbn);
            var resultString = RestClient.makeApiCall(requestUrl);
            var product = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(resultString);


        return product;
    }
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Product> model = new List<Product>();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SearchViewModel VM)
    {
        var search = VM.searchValue.Trim();
        var searchValues = search.Replace(Environment.NewLine, ",").Split(',');

        List<Product> model = new List<Product>();
        foreach (var p in searchValues)
        {
            model = ApiCalls.GetByISBN(p).products;
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

And my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Saxo.Web.Models.Product>
@{ 
    Html.RenderAction("Search");
}
<h1>Produkter</h1>
@ViewBag.Arr
@if (Model != null)
{
    foreach (var m in Model)
    {
        <p>@m.alias</p>
    }
}
```

I have tried different methods like:

```
var product = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(resultString);
```

I only get the last object. It doesnt stack in List. 
hope u guys can help.

JSON:

```
   {
   "products":[  
      {  
         "id":"3042442",
         "alias":"marte-meo-i-praksis_pernille-roug_haeftet_9788741201122",
       }
    ]
}
```

Comment: show us the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The json you posted match the `rootObject` not `Product`, so you have to deserialize using the `rootObject`:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<rootObject>(resultString);
```

this will deserialize the json into a an instance of `rootObject` that will have all the products in its `List<Product>` property.

Comment: I do get a result. But i dont get it in list.

Comment: you mean the `products` property list is empty?

Comment: also, I'm assuming that the json you posted was just a trimmed down version of the actual json from the response, as it contain only a single product in the collection. The actual json has more products and only one is being added to the deserialized `products` collection?

Comment: No its not empty, it just output the last product and not As a list of products. Yes it is trimmed down, but the rest is unneeded info about the product.

Comment: when you say "it just output the last product" do you mean the `products` list of the `rootObject` instance has a single instance of a product? The full version of the json contain multiple products in the array? I can't repro the issue that you are describing. See this .net fiddle for reference: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xgTOmH

Comment: Oooh no, now i see the problem! I was adding a new product the whole time. Didnt see that the array should be like that.